# Adding JSON in the specified place by JSONPath

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I'm getting JSON and JSONPath from a user. The user also giving me a new content (value or object) that he want add to his JSON. I'm trying to create a method which will add new content to the path specified by JSONPath.

Method input: json, jsonpath, newcontent(string)
Method output: new json with added newcontent

**JSON example**

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**JSONPath example**

```
$.store
```

**Object to add**

```
movie [title : The Godfather]
```

**Method returns**

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ],
    "movie": [
      {
        "title" : "The Godfather"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string ApplyChange(string originalJson, string path, string jsonToAdd)
{
    var root = JObject.Parse(originalJson);
    var node = root.SelectToken(path);
    switch (node.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Object:
        {
            var objectToMerge = JObject.Parse("{" + jsonToAdd + "}");
            ((JObject)node).Merge(objectToMerge);
            break;
        }
        case JTokenType.Array:
        {
            var objectToMerge = new JArray(JToken.Parse(jsonToAdd));
            ((JArray)node).Merge(objectToMerge);
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    return root.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i know about this way - but the data which user wants to add will be dynamically change.

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, how is this data specified exactly? Can you easily parse it to a valid JSON object ?

Comment: User gives me a data (which he wants to add) in a JSON format. Ex. `"movie": [
      {
        "title" : "sometitle"
      }
    ]
` or `"title": "sometitle"` Data could have other values. That books and movie was just an example :).

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, ok, is it always a property? Or can it be a full object?

Comment: It can be a full object too.

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, ah, it's annoying... it makes it more difficult to parse. It's hard to answer precisely without knowing the exact specs of how it's supposed to work. If it's a property, it's clear that you just need to add it to the object specified by the path. But if it's an object, what does it mean? What are you supposed to do with it?

Comment: Example - if user wants to add new category at store with values he gives me a path to place where new category should be and specifies new content as a JSON: `"bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }`

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, see my edited answer. It should work for adding a property to an existing object, and adding an object to an existing array.

Comment: It works (have no idea about existing Merge method :/), but i've got one more question about this code. What if user wants add property to path like `$.store.book[*]` - that should add new property to all books, but program throws me an exception `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Path returned multiple tokens.`

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, you need to use `SelectTokens` instead of `SelectToken`, and loop over the result

Comment: More precisely - is there any way to do it in one metod? I need to parse JsonPath an choose if i need to use SelectToken or SelectTokens?

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist, just use `SelectTokens` all the time. If the path matches only one node, it will return only one node, and the loop will only run once.

Comment: Works! Thanks for your time.